# How to find control points Bezier

Tags: java, javascript, actionscript-3, flash

Are the coordinates of the beginning of `Po (x 1, y 1)`, the coordinates of the maximum arc `T (x4, y4) == t (0.5)` and the coordinates of the end of `P3 (x3, y3)`. How to find data on these control points? As detailed as possible. (Apologies for the fractured language, Google Translate).
curve of the third order, you need to find the coordinates of `P1`, `P2`

I know on the condition that P1 and P2 belong to the segments forming the corner, and that these points are mirrored

Comment: This is more a math question. You should write that you are talking about a quadratic bezier curve (to make your question more specific for search engines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly (not sure though)... this link should be helpful:

[Finding the Control Points of a Bezier Curve](http://blog.sklambert.com/finding-the-control-points-of-a-bezier-curve/)

Also comment to the "bokan" comment: i think in this case we're talking about cubic not quadratic bezier curve... 2 control points are mentioned...